# Syntax used in CSS files declared are different from the way it is used

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am using React. I am not able to understand why the declaration inside css file is (floating-Workups) [ Notice use of `-`] but when used inside in .tsx file it is floatingWorkups [ `-` is removed ] Why it is not being used as floating-Workups.

In css files below is declared but

```js
.floating-Workups {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

In .tsx file i am using

```js
import styles from './app.css';
<div className={styles.floatingWorkups}>
</div>
```

Any pointer can help ?

Comment: I believe this is happening because you're importing and using the css like a CSS Module. Since the CSS is being imported and used like an object in JS, it's expecting camelCase. Try instead using `import './app.scss'` at the top and use `className="floating-workups"` if possible. Here's some more context on styling in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Comment: `styles['floating-Workups']`